# Open Windows child_process exec in its own console window, from Node JS

Tags: node.js, windows, exec, child-process

I am under Windows and Node JS/Express, using installed 'child_process' module.
I need to launch the executable 'c:\test\test.exe' - a windows console application - from Node JS.
 I can launch non-console applications but I'm having problems with the console ones;
e.g. I have tried the simple statement:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
..............    
childProcess.execFile(process.env.C_APP_EXEC_NAME);
```

which works fine with 'full_path\WINWORD.EXE' but not with c:\test\test.exe.
I want to add that I need to have the console opened since the test.exe interacts with the user through it.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is by bringing together several pieces, Node JS- and Windows-related:
the call should be

```
childProcess.exec("start cmd @cmd /k " + process.env.C_APP_EXEC_NAME);
```

The process.env.C_APP_EXEC_NAME is either the full path of the test.exe file or its relative path to the Node JS application's root directory
HTH

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spawn` as well.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', PATH_TO_EXE], { detached: true })

// Event handlers for the child process
child.on('data', (data) => {})
child.on('error', (error) => {})
child.on('close', (code) => {})
```